# Set edittext inputtype created dynamically - causes errors

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers

I have a problem with dynamically created EditText. I create dialog, with some elements, and also EditText. I want it to have InputType only number. So I try doing that like:

```
EditText itemsCount = new EditText(this);
itemsCount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
lila.addView(itemsCount);
```

`lila` is LinearLayout, where I am adding more views.
And that's where weird behavior begins. On `lenovo tablet` I cannot enter any data. On my `S3` i can enter data, hovever I cannot use backspace...
When I will add EditText without determining InputType, everything works as it should, but user can also enter text, and that's what i do not want...

Any ideas what can causing those bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` instead.